# Increment [ESP] causing jump over one byte (anti stepping or anti debugging)

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

What purpose function dap_jump_one_byte, this function only incrementing [esp] but some
debugger have different result when stepover and step into performed.

when we do stepover through this function debugger execute directly do normal execution flow (run) so stepover not performed well.
then when we do step into one byte jump performed by this function skip byte 0xBE at 0x0F4040D0.

can someone explain what purpose of this function more detail.

[image]

function dap_jump_one_byte
this function make, ida, olly, and x32Dbg can't stepover

[image]

Comment: For "can someone explain what purpose of this function more detail.", which part do you not understand? It seems like you know that it increments the return address by 1, to jump over the byte at `0x0F4040D0`. It's also not clear to me what you mean by "so stepover not performed well".

Comment: oh, sorry. whether this dap_jump_one_byte function is intended for the use of antidebug trick or other purposes. because the call of this function is almost in every other function.

Comment: It might cause the disassembly of the following code to be misaligned in case the tool is not smart enough to detect the inserted byte as garbage. E.g. a naive disassembler would think that `0xbe` is the start of the next instruction so it would show `mov esi, 2a5c04beh` and then probably get totally out of sync.

Comment: yes it's completely out of sync. ida, olly, and x32Dbg have different result. "so stepover not performed well" @ThomasJager stepover cannot be performed. just run trough like we normally press F9 on IDA. so why stepover behave like this.

Comment: Trivial anti-debugging technique. The function skips the next byte after the call. Some disassemblers that are not descending and cannot do control flow analysis will be fouled by the extra byte and show a wrong listing. If you use a debugger to step **over** the call then the artificial `int3` instruction inserted by the debugger will never be triggered because it's in the skipped byte. Use "Execute until" (e.g. F4 in x64dbg) on the second byte from the call. Or just nop the call and the extra byte (CTRL+F9 in x64dbg).

Comment: Since the CPU only supports single stepping, presumably step over works by putting a temporary breakpoint after the `call` which then won't be hit if the called function does not return to the expected place.

Comment: whether there are any articles or reviews regarding artificial int3. please share to me. or related to this @MargaretBloom, if some code performs int2d this garbage byte 0xBE affected by byte scission or not.

Comment: Unlike the title of this question suggests, it is not `esp` that is being incremented, it is the `dword [esp]`. This memory location on the stack always holds the near return address when the function is called. Therefore the function returns to a location that's one byte after the normal return address. Debuggers implement "step over" for a near call instruction by placing an `int3` (byte 0CCh) opcode into the byte after the call instruction, assuming that the function will do a normal return and then execute the breakpoint instruction (`int3`) to return control to the debugger

Comment: my apologies, you right sir.

Comment: Reminder: not everyone is male so "sir" isn't a good choice for people you don't know.